# trouble installing suggested packages to play dvds on 14.04

Tags: dvd

I have finally successfully installed the ubuntu restricted extras as well as the libdvdread4 for the cc2, but still can't play dvds.

Comment: Since you edited your question and completely changed its meaning, the title no longer matches the content.

Comment: You need `libdvdcss2` in order to decrypt commercial DVDs. Do you have it? If not, just Google it; it is not provided in the official Ubuntu repositories, as it may be illegal in some jurisdictions (it is legal in France, where its developers are located).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have the CD-ROM box checked on the screen below.

[image]

Uncheck it and click close. You'll be asked for your password in here somewhere.

After that, retry your install.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it (that box isn't present at all).  I was excited there for a minute.  Anything else?

Comment: Blast! I've seen similar issues and was sure that'd be it. It has to be something sources-list related.